# network interface route gateway information in freebsd

Tags: c, freebsd, network-interface

Can I get route gateway information for an interface (programmingly) using getifaddrs() or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. See the manual page for `route(4)`.

Comment: Thanks Ronald, this seems like what I need. I will update once I try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sysctl()` to dump routing information. In the MIB, the first value has to be set to `CTL_NET` and the second to `AF_ROUTE`.

Comment: You will find lots of code in Richard Stevens' seminal book on "UNIX Network Programming". The code examples are provided here: http://www.kohala.com/start/unpv12e.html. Routing is covered in Chapter 17.

Answer (score 0):

If availabel (as it's freebsd) you could read out `/proc/net/route`.

Comment: On FreeBSD `procfs` only contains info about processes. See `procfs(5)`.